# SUM several CASE results

Tags: sql-server, case, sum

Given:

```
 CASE 
     WHEN A IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0
 END AS [A]
, CASE
     WHEN B IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0
 END AS [B]
, CASE
     WHEN C IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 
 END AS [C]
```

---

How can I SUM  A+B+C being the results of 3 different CASE WHEN

Answer (score 1):

You did not specify your RDBMS (SQL Server, Oracle, etc.), but if it supports [Common Table Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), you could encapsulate your main select logic in a `CTE` and select/sum from it.  Here is a solution using SQL Server.

```
Declare @T table (A int, B int, C int)
insert into @T(A,B,C) values(null,2,null)

;WITH _cte
AS (
    SELECT CASE 
            WHEN A IS NULL
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END AS [A]
        ,CASE 
            WHEN B IS NULL
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END AS [B]
        ,CASE 
            WHEN C IS NULL
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END AS [C]
    FROM @T
    )
SELECT A + B + C as Results
FROM _cte
```

---

```
Results
2
```

---

As a comment pointed out, you don't *need* a common table expression.  A derived table will also serve the purpose

```
Declare @T table (A int, B int, C int)
insert into @T(A,B,C) values(null,2,null)
SELECT A + B + C AS Results
FROM (
    SELECT CASE 
            WHEN A IS NULL
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END AS [A]
        ,CASE 
            WHEN B IS NULL
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END AS [B]
        ,CASE 
            WHEN C IS NULL
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END AS [C]
    FROM @T
    ) a
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this one?
Please share your opinion on this. what is the difference between this solution and using CTE in terms of performance?

```
select sum(CASE
             WHEN A IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
        + 
       sum(CASE
             WHEN B IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
        + 
       sum(CASE
             WHEN C IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) sum_result
  from <Your_Table>;
```

Answer (score 0):

*Answer originally left as a comment by the question author:*

Ended up doing the following (this is SQL Server)

```
WITH T AS (
CASE 
     WHEN A IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0
 END AS [A]
, CASE
     WHEN B IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0
 END AS [B]
, CASE
     WHEN C IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 
 END AS [C]
) 
Select
*
From T
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT (A+B+C) AS [SUM] 
FROM(CASE 
     WHEN A IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0
 END AS [A]
, CASE
     WHEN B IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0
 END AS [B]
, CASE
     WHEN C IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 
 END AS [C])T;
```